# Bootstrap responsive navbar with toggle-navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for creating a new project Template in order to convert `Wordpress Template` to `Bootstrap Template`.

I'm working on `navbar` and I'm getting an issue with `responsive-design` and `toggle-navigation`

When I'm in `laptop device`, my navbar is well-defined as I want. But, with `smartphone device` for example, the toggle-navigation doesn't display my navbar as I would like to get. Especially with `navbar-left` and `navbar-right`.

Laptop device :

[image]

Smartphone device :

[image]

I would like to get in smartphone view all elements aligned vertically and it's not the case for `www.coe.int` and `languages with glyphicons`

This is my HTML script :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                  <li><a id="coe" href="http://www.coe.int">WWW.COE.INT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-middle">
                <li><a class="active" href="#">EUROPEAN PHARMACOPOEIA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHARMEUROPA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OTHER PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Languages</a></li>
                <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And my CSS part :

```
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

/* ######################## */
/*        HEADER PART       */
/* ######################## */

header{
    background-color:  #e8e8e8;
}

header a{
    color:  #a5a5a4;
}

/* Bootstrap Stuff */

nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-static-top {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}

a#coe {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-middle > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #1b7eac;
    color: black;
    transition: all 0.2s;
       }


ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-middle > li > a:focus{
    background-color: #1b7eac;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.2s;
       }
```

Could you help me to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

My reputation does not allow me to comment unfortunately as this certainly be a comment. 
But have you tried simply altering the text size using media queries to get your desired result?

--EDIT-----

I am assuming you already have the toggle button already working. 
In which case If you wish to align them vertically you can use the bootstrap operator

col-sm-4 (for three items vertically aligned)

col-sm-3 (for 4 items vertically aligned)

Which will give each element their own space and align them vertically.

But remember you need to have a container then row then this property like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">item here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">item here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">item here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Yes I tried and it doesn't solve the problem. I don't thing it's about `font-size` but maybe the navbar area (left, middle and right)

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly you wish to just align them vertically ? so they stack on top of eachother?  or so they look like they do in laptop view?

Comment: align them vertically with toggle-navigation. In laptow view it's good, but not with smaller views

Comment: It doesn't work because it's a navbar and you don't have to use `col-*` in this element.